# Can't pipe into netcat

Tags: pipe, docker, netcat

I have a squid proxy running in a docker container, started like this:

```
docker run --privileged -d --publish=3128:3128 --name foo squid
```

I want to get some information from it, from another container called `bar`.

```
docker run --rm -it --name bar ubuntu:trusty bash
```

If I run this in the `bar` container:

```
nc 172.17.0.1 3128
HEAD /
```

Then I get some output from the server. But if I run this:

```
echo 'HEAD /' | nc 172.17.0.1 3128
```

I get nothing. Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because netcat exits
shortly after getting an end-of-file on its standard input.  Try

```
(echo 'HEAD /'; sleep 5) | nc 172.17.0.1 3128
```

to keep netcat's local input open long enough
for it to read the network data and write it to the standard output. 
The `5` is the number of seconds to delay.

Netcat has an option to deal with this. If you specify a negative quit timeout, it will wait for the network connection to close instead of quitting after EOF on stdin:

```
echo 'HEAD /' | nc -q -1 172.17.0.1 3128
```

Comment: OK, that works. But if I run it on my host (not in a container), I don't need the `sleep 5`. Is there a difference in the buffer sizes, or something?

Comment: Ah, apparently netcat has a flag to help with this: `-q -1` will tell it not to quit after receiving EOF; it waits instead for the connection to close.